# ColdFusion 10 REST API: How to set status code 201 without RestSetResponse()

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm using ColdFusion 10's new built-in REST API and I'd like to return a status code of 201 (Created).  I first tried the RestSetResponse() approach that's described here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html. It works well, except that it forces you to set the function's returntype to "void".  The problem with "void" is that whenever I throw an exception, it no longer returns the proper JSON error message.

Throwing this exception:

```
<cfthrow errorcode="400" message="Validation error." />
```

Returns a nicely formatted JSON when the returntype is "struct":

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json

{"Message":"Validation error."}
```

But when the returntype is "void" (which is required to use RestSetResponse(), the response is some ugly HTML response.

Because of this, I had to revert to using returntype "struct", gave up on RestSetResponse(), and tried this:

```
<cfheader statusCode="201" statusText="Created" />
```

But it doesn't work. It seems that ColdFusion overwrites the statusCode and always returns 200 (OK) when it's successful. Anyone know of a way to change the status code to 201 without setting the returntype of the function to "void"?

Comment: Can't you specify custom content in the response struct as described  [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_3)?

Comment: I can't do that. As mentioned in my question, using RestSetResponse() requires that the returntype is "void", which no longer honors the proper JSON response in case of an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a good reason why `restSetResponse()` should require a returntype of void, but have verified it is ignored if this is not the case. Which is a bit rubbish.

The only thing I can think by way of working around your situation is to roll-your-own struct with the error detail in it, then use that as the `content` value set for the `restSetResponse()` call.

This is a bit jerry-built, but you're constrainted by the jerry-built-ness of ColdFusion in this instance, I think.

I've [logged a bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3546046) relating to this.

Comment: Just FYI, I took this issue as inspiration for a blog article, if you're interested: http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/restsetresponse-requires-method-to-be.html.

Comment: Thanks Adam for the detailed blog post.  I hope it serves as a useful artifact for others who encounter this same problem.