# Get the output of RestSetResponse without making HTTP request

Tags: rest, coldfusion

I have a minimal (example) REST end-point `test/people.cfc`:

```
component
  restpath = "test/people/"
  rest     = true
{
  remote void function create(
    required  string   first_name restargsource = "Form",
    required  string   last_name  restargsource = "Form"
  )
    httpmethod  = "POST"
    restpath    = ""
    produces    = "application/json"
  {
    // Simulate adding person to database.
    ArrayAppend(
      Application.people,
      { "first_name" = first_name, "last_name" = last_name }
    );

    // Simulate getting people from database.
    var people = Application.people;

    restSetResponse( {
      "status"  = 201,
      "content" = SerializeJSON( people )
    } );
  }
}
```

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711287/coldfusion-10-rest-api-how-to-set-status-code-201-without-restsetresponse) and in the [ColdFusion documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/restsetresponse.html):

> Note: ColdFusion ignores the function's return value and uses the response set using the `RestSetResponse()` function.

So the `void` return type for the function appears to be correct for the REST function.

Now, I know I can call it from a CFM page using:

```
httpService = new http(method = "POST", url = "https://localhost/rest/test/people"); 
httpService.addParam( name = "first_name", type = "formfield", value = "Alice" ); 
httpService.addParam( name = "last_name",  type = "formfield", value = "Adams" ); 
result = httpService.send().getPrefix();
```

However, I would like to call the function without making a HTTP request.

Firstly, the REST CFCs do not appear to be accessible from within the REST directory. This can be solved simply by creating a mapping in the ColdFusion admin panel to the root path of the REST service.

I can then do:

```
<cfscript>
Application.people = [];

people = new restmapping.test.People();

people.create( "Alice", "Adams" );

WriteDump( application.people );
</cfscript>
```

This calls the function directly and the output shows it has added the person. However, the response from the REST function has disappeared into the aether. Does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve the response's HTTP status code and content (as a minimum - preferably all the HTTP headers)?

**Update - Integration Testing Scenario**:

This is one use-case (of several) where calling the REST end-point via a HTTP request has knock-on effects that can be mitigated by invoking the end-point directly as a method of a component.

```
<cfscript>
// Create an instance of the REST end-point component without
// calling it via HTTP request.
endPoint = new restfiles.test.TestRESTEndPoint();

transaction {
  try {
    // Call a method on the end-point without making a HTTP request.
    endPoint.addValueToDatabase( 1, 'abcd' );
    assert( getRESTStatusCode(), 201 );
    assert( getRESTResponseText(), '{"id":1,"value":"abcd"}' );
    // Call another method on the end-point without making a HTTP request.
    endPoint.updateValueInDatabase( 1, 'dcba' );
    assert( getRESTStatusCode(), 200 );
    assert( getRESTResponseText(), '{"id":1,"value":"dcba"}' );
    // Call a third method on the end-point without making a HTTP request.
    endPoint.deleteValueInDatabase( 1 );
    assert( getRESTStatusCode(), 204 );
    assert( getRESTResponseText(), '' );
  }
  catch ( any e )
  {
    WriteDump( e );
  }
  finally
  {
    transaction action="rollback";
  }
}
</cfscript>
```

Calling each REST function via a HTTP request will commit the data to the database after each request - cleaning up between tests where the data has been committed can get very complicated and often results in needing to flashback the database to a previous state (resulting in integration tests being unable to be run in parallel with any other tests and periods of unavailability during flashbacks). Being able to call the REST end-points without making lots of atomic HTTP requests and instead bundle them into a single transaction which can be rolled back means the testing can be performed in a single user's session.

So, how can I get the HTTP status code and response text which have been set by `RestSetResponse()` when I create an instance of the REST component and invoke the function representing the REST path directly (without using a HTTP request)?

Comment: So you want to get the HTTP response, without doing a HTTP-request? Don't think this is possible

Comment: @XavierL. No, I don't want the HTTP response per se - I want to see the result/side-effects of calling the `RestSetResponse()` function. For example, in a CFM page I can use `GetPageContext().getCFOutput().getBuffer().toString()` to get the current (unflushed) output for the page but I don't know of an equivalent solution for where the output would reside for `RestSetResponse()`.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are looking for. If you are using the `RestSetResponse()` method than _you_ are setting the output response overriding whatever would have been set before it. Right?

Comment: @Miguel-F That is probably correct - the question is, before the response is returned by the REST end-point and after it has been set by `RestSetResponse()` where are the values for the HTTP header values and the HTTP response  stored and how do I read them back from the output data structure/buffer?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I suspect the HTTP headers are not set unless you actually make an HTTP request.

Comment: @Miguel-F They must be stored somewhere so that when the request is sent then they can be set at that time. It may be that the data is stored privately and there is no public API available to access that data and it is impossible to answer this question; however there may be an API (documented or undocumented) and, if so, I'd like to try to find it.

Comment: Fair enough. I will try to get some Adobe folks to take a look at your question.

Answer (score 1):

@MT0,

The solution will* involve a few steps:

1. Change `remote void function create` to `remote struct function create`
2. Add `var result = {"status"  = 201, "content" = SerializeJSON( people )}`
3. Change your `restSetResponse(..)` call to `restSetResponse(result)`
4. Add `return result;`

* The solution will not currently work, b/c ColdFusion ticket [CF-3546046](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-3546046) was not fixed completely. I've asked Adobe to re-open it and also filed [CF-4198298](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4198298) to get this issue fixed, just in case CF-3546046 isn't re-opened. Please see my most recent comment on CF-3546046, and feel free to vote for either ticket. Once either is fixed completely, then the above-listed changes to your code will allow it to set the correct HTTP response when called via REST and to return the function's return variable when invoked directly. Note: you could also specify a `headers` struct w/in the `result` struct in step 2, if you also want to return headers when the function is invoked directly.

Thanks!,
-Aaron Neff

Comment: If the architecture was changed to follow this pattern then every REST function would have the return type `struct` which contains the HTTP status code, headers and content. In this case, why would the `RestSetResponse()` function call be required? It could be applied in the background by ColdFusion using the returned struct when called from a REST context.

Comment: I would agree with the conclusions of @AdamCameron [2014 blog post](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/04/coldfusion-rest-services-and.html), that, in my example, the return value should be the contents of the `people` variable (not the struct passed to `RestSetResponse()`) and that a `null` response should be allowed in cases where the status code is `204 - No Content` or `4??` but ColdFusion does not allow this. I would also think that the HTTP status and headers should be set using a similar method to `<cfheader>` (which would then allow access via `getPageContext().getResponse()`).

Comment: The following RestSetResponse() doc note (added per CF-3546046), describes the intended behavior: "Note: ColdFusion ignores the function's return value and uses the response set using the RestSetResponse() function." Adobe documented the intended behavior, but never implemented the intended behavior.

Comment: I filed CF-4198298 to clarify the following: 1) If a non-void function is invoked directly, it should return a variable like it currently does. Thus, any RestSetResponse() is ignored. 2) If a non-void function is invoked via REST, it should behave as documented. Thus, the return is ignored.

Comment: When invoked directly, the return value could be the contents of the `people` variable. Yes. I only used the struct of status/headers/content as an example b/c you wanted to get at those details. The return variable wouldn't be married to the RestSetResponse(). RestSetResponse() could still return the array. And the return variable could either be the same array, or a struct containing the array as well as the status/headers/content.

Comment: Basically, I was suggesting that CF at least behave as documented. I agree with 1) the usefulness of returning `null` to set a `204` and 2) the usefulness of being able to access the REST response post-`RestSetResult()` via `getPageContext()` or other means.